# How to deal with a non responsive app/process?

Tags: mac, macos

Firefox does not respond. How can I quit it other than by Force Quit?

[image]

I can kill it by using the left upper button (X). Is there a better method other than to Force Quit?

Comment: What don't you like about sing force quit?  Is there a problem you're trying to solve that using force quit isn't good/suitable for?

Comment: @fsb Yes, I am writing blog in the firefox, if I Force Quit the firefox, mybe the text written by me will lost. I am just looking for if there is a better solution.

Comment: @aircraft Killing the application will delete what you wrote - quit, force quit, or whatever. There is no way around this. I recommend blogging in Word, Pages, TextEdit, etc - then copying and pasting into your site.

Comment: okay. i kown that now.